# Adjusting Legend Box Dimensions To Fit Flush With Text in R

Tags: r, plot, graphics, legend, fill

I would like to adjust the legend box, so that it sits flush with the text it contains.

Current problem producing space above, below and either side:

```
y <- runif(500,0,0.5)
x <- seq(1,500,1)
plot(x,y)
legend(x=1, y=0.1,expression('Upper Gate'), box.lwd = 0,box.col =adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75),bg=adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75))
legend(x=1, y=0.25,expression('Middle Gate'), box.lwd = 0,box.col =adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75),bg=adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75))
legend(x=1, y=0.5,expression('Bottom Gate'), box.lwd = 0,box.col =adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75),bg=adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75))
```

which produces:[image]
I have tried altering the box positioning with no success:

```
y <- runif(500,0,0.5)
x <- seq(1,500,1)
plot(x,y)
legend(x=c(10,90), y=c(0.44,0.46),expression('Upper Gate'), box.lwd = 0,box.col =adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75),bg=adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75))
legend(x=c(10,90), y=c(0.19,0.21),expression('Middle Gate'), box.lwd = 0,box.col =adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75),bg=adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75))
legend(x=c(10,90), y=c(0.01,0.015),expression('Bottom Gate'), box.lwd = 0,box.col =adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75),bg=adjustcolor("grey", alpha=0.75))
```

which produces:[image]

But I really want something akin to this:[image]

Any help would be much appreciated, **specifically in base graphics**!

Comment: It is not exactly what you asked,  but you could make the labels you want using text and rect.

Comment: Thanks, this worked... sort of, but it's going to be painful.